# gitignore not ignoring files on windows vb.net

Tags: git, gitignore

I created a folder, added some code, created a `.gitignore` txt file with the following:

```
*.cache
*.dll
```

Then I run these commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin htttps://...
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git status
```

And I keep on seeing .dll and .cache files... Why isn't .gitignore working?

I also tried :

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

But the dll and cache files are still being added.

My `.gitignore` is in the root directory (where I ran `git init`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `.gitignore` file is not known to your git repository yet (which happens when you haven't committed the file yet), then the `.gitignore` file is not yet active. Try committing the file first (`git add .gitignore`, and `git commit`), before trying to add other files.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore